# Internal transactions don't affect balance?

Tags: balances, internal-transactions

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x74fafc61782bdaf8abedc526cd18dbf51e0890d1#internaltx

There is an internal transaction sending 0.000000000000001 ETH to this address yet balance is still 0. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The transaction seems to have failed. TxReceipt Status:Fail
That's probably why the balance is not showing.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xfbe32dc7f09a6e3e75cb2b52e425ce72cf7b037959d48a9ac4560558cf69030e

Comment: Yeah it's something to do with [running out of gas at the subsequent transaction](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Ethereum-Development-Best-Practices/wiki/Fallback-functions-and-the-fundamental-limitations-of-using-send()-in-Ethereum-&-Solidity). Haven't figured out how to solve it yet though. What happens is I send a transaction and that triggers between-contract transfer and I need to make sure enough gas is passed to complete that.

Comment: @tsotsi If you use `transfer` the recipient can only use 2300 gas ([gas stipend](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#sending-and-receiving-ether)). The safest solution is to create your own payable method in the recipient contract. Another solution is also stated in the link is to use the low-level `recipient.call.value(1 eth)()`.